# hazelcast webfilter when Migrating to springboot 3 with jdk17

Tags: hazelcast, java-17, spring-boot-3

I have a spring boot 2 application with jdk8 that uses hazelcast to share https seesions which has been migrated to spring boot 3 with jdk17.

it configures a bean of HazelcastInstance and for session replication it has a webfilter which has as properties the instance name and the sticky session set to false as shown in the hazelcast site (https://docs.hazelcast.com/tutorials/springboot-webfilter-session-replication)
The problem is that the hazelcast WebFilter uses internally javax.servlet.Filter which can't used with jdk17.

An ideas on how to solve this?

is it equivalent to use @EnableHazelcastHttpSession?

I've tried using @EnableHazelcastHttpSession, but not ssure if this will have the same behaviour

Comment: Does Hazelcast [support JDK-17](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/installation/supported-jvms)?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at old documents. If you are using SpringBoot 3.1 follow this link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/java-hazelcast.html
You don't need to create any WebFilter

The sample for hazelcast is here
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/3.1.2/spring-session-samples/spring-session-sample-boot-hazelcast